# Using DATEADD in SQL INSERT query with hapi.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-insert

I want to import the unix timestamp (contained in an received Json body) into my MSSQL database as a human readable time using Node.js. Therefore I have converted the request object directly in the Insert query. I set the datatype "datetime" in the SQL Server.

The Json body looks like this:

```
{
  "device":"887B53",
  "data":"4660000000000062b4a8",
  "station":"1B2C",
  "rssi":"-123",
  "time":"1586096200"
}
```

I use a hapi server for routing:

```
  server.route({

        method: 'POST',
        path: '/',
        handler: async (request, h) => {

            try {

                const datetime = DATEADD(ss, request.payload.time, '19700101');

                await pool.query("INSERT INTO mytable(timestamp)VALUES('"+datetime+"')");

                return h.response('Callback received').code(200);
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log("SQL Err", err.stack);
                return 'Error';
            }

        }

    });
```

At first it worked exactly as I expected it to. But than I've messed up something and it no longer works. I have absolutely no idea what happened and can't find the issue.

This error is thrown:

> at Request._lifecycle (C:\Users\AW\sqltest\node_modules@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:365:68)
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
>   at async Request._execute (C:\Users\AW\sqltest\node_modules@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:274:9)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want `dateadd()` *within* the query rather than in javascript. Something like:

```
try {
    const request = pool.request()
    request.input('mytimestamp', sql.VarChar, request.payload.time)
    await request.query(
        "INSERT INTO mytable(timestamp) VALUES(DATEADD(ss, @mytimestamp, '19700101'))"
    );
    return h.response('Callback received').code(200);
}
```

Note that this uses a parameterized query rather than mungling the parameter into the query string - which is both safer and more efficient.

Comment: Is thos procedure for parameterizing also possable with MSSQL-Node. Unfortunately I still get an error. It could be an hapi issue aswell.

Comment: @Karol-Kahn: please see my edited answer. Does this work in MSSQL / Node?

Comment: unfortunately not :/   ```:48)
    at exports.execute (C:\Users\Artur\sqltest\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:36)
    at Request._lifecycle (C:\Users\Artur\sqltest\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:365:68)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Request._execute (C:\Users\Artur\sqltest\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:274:
9)´´´

I opened a new question. There you can see little bit more from code. request object is allready used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065500/parametized-insert-query-with-node-mssql