# Parametized INSERT query with node-mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, parameters, sql-insert

I want to parametrize an insert query with node.js for SQL Server. Unfortunately it will not work and I don't really know if it's a Node module issue or a syntax failure.

Code:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/',
    handler: async (request, h) => {

    try {
        await pool.query("INSERT INTO sigfoxmessages(device,data,station,rssi,unix_timestamp) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5))"
        [request.payload.device, request.payload.data, request.payload.station, request.payload.rssi, request.payload.time]);

        return h.response('Callback received').code(200);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("SQL Err", err.stack);
        return 'Error';
    }
  }
});
```

Error:

> at exports.Manager.execute (C:\Users\A\sqltest\node_modules@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:60: 33)
>   at Object.internals.handler (C:\Users\A\sqltest\node_modules@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46 :48)
>   at exports.execute (C:\Users\A\sqltest\node_modules@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:36)
>   at Request._lifecycle (C:\Users\A\sqltest\node_modules@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:365:68)
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
>   at async Request._execute (C:\Users\A\sqltest\node_modules@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:274: 9)

Used node modules:

- hapi/hapi 19.0.5
- mssql: 6.0.1

Does anyone have an idea or or a suggestion?

Comment: Try to get the **error message** - not just the stack trace - and post it here!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for `mssql` you can use es6 template literals in you INSERT statement.

```
pool.query`INSERT INTO sigfoxmessages (device,data,station,rssi,unix_timestamp) VALUES(${request.payload.device}, ${request.payload.data}, ${request.payload.station}, ${request.payload.rssi}, ${request.payload.time}))`
```

Docs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: Thanks for the support, for some reason I have to add an apostrophe to make it work: `VALUES('${device}','${data}','${station}','${rssi}',DATEADD(ss, ${time}, '19700101'),'${input1}','${input2}'))`

Comment: Without brackets? Still same issue like without apostrophe...node refers to tedious package:                               at Parser.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\A\sqltest\node_modules\tedious\lib\token
\token-stream-parser.js:37:14)

Comment: Interesting.. docs say different. But I guess if you managed to get it working